# Node.js get original file size from source when copying to another destination

Tags: node.js

I have a watcher from the chokidar package to watch files and sub directories inside a designated folder.

Whenever I copy some big file from one source to this folder, I get more than one 'filechange' event for that file from the watcher. I get why the watcher reports more than one file change event, but I'm supposed to stream copied data to the server upon these filechange events, and this part makes my code very VERY complicated.

Is there a way I can get the original file size from the source destination so that I can regulate when it is safe to start streaming?

Comment: Does the `stats` variable sent by chokidar on file `change` event has wrong size data? `watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) { if (stats) console.log(stats.size); });`

Comment: no the size is accurate, but it emits multiple change events in the middle of the copying that makes callback handling frustrating

Answer (score 3):

Use the asynchronous method [`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback):

```
fs.stat(__dirname + '/path/to/original/file.ext', function (err, stat) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(stat.size);
    // do something with it
});
```

Comment: but the watcher can only watch files in the designated directory. Is there a way I can get the filepath to the original file on filechange? Does Fs.Stats have any features related?

Comment: @user3467433 I'm not sure. You should provide a link to the module you're using and I'll take a look.